# Drawing outside a UICollectionViewCell's bounds when using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Has anyone been able to draw outside the bounds of a `UICollectionViewCell` without the cell clipping to its bounds?  I have a vanilla collection view that uses a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (horizontal) and I would like to be able to draw a path outside the bounds of the `UICollectionViewCell` without disrupting any of the layout provided by `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Setting `clipsToBounds` to `NO` does not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by setting the cell's layer's maskToBounds property to NO. (You'll need to bring in the QuartzCore framework and import it into the View Controller…)

If that doesn't work, try setting the cell's contentView's layer's maskToBounds property to NO.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For me using maskToBounds did the job

```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()       
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
   }
```